# Create a simple infinite carousel using jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, carousel, infinite-scroll

So here's what I'm trying to do.
I'm trying to create a simple responsive carousel from scratch the only part I have problem with so far is detecting the last item in the carousel and starting it over so it looks infinite. What's the best approach to this?

Also I'm trying to make it so on mobile devices you would be able to drag on the carousel in order to see more items and that part is not big deal but I have the same issue as the desktop version and I just want to find a way to make it infinite.

[JsFidle](https://jsfiddle.net/17r2v6hs/6/)

HTML:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-products-carousel">
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">1</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">2</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">3</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">4</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">5</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">6</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">8</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">9</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <span class="scroll-right text-white">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.nav-products-carousel {
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        background: rgb(201, 201, 116);
    }

    div.nav-item {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        white-space: initial;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .scroll-right {
        right: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        background: #ccc;
        padding-top: 5%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
        background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    }
```

JQUERY:

```
var scrolled = 0;
$(document).on('click', '.scroll-right', function() {
    scrolled = scrolled + 250;
    $('.nav-products-carousel').stop().animate({
        scrollLeft: scrolled
    });
});
```

Comment: Please setup JsFiddle correctly. It has missing jQuery and BootStrap. Also, it don't work at all.

Comment: @AmitKB Sorry about that. I updated the JsFiddle with bootstrap and jquery 1.9. seems to be working for me now https://jsfiddle.net/17r2v6hs/6/

Comment: Answer is posted. JsFiddle requires external link reference over 'https' not 'http'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working demo in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/17r2v6hs/8/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var scrolled = 0,
   scrollDistance = 210, // Scrolling at at time
    maxToScroll, // Maximum to scroll left
  el; // Target element
    
  // Get target element reference
  el = $('.nav-products-carousel');
  
  // calculate maximum to scroll
  // this helps to make last element to appear correctly
  maxToScroll = el.width() + scrollDistance;

  $(document).on('click', function() {
      if ( scrolled < maxToScroll ){
        scrolled = scrolled + scrollDistance;
        el.stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: scrolled
        });
      }
      else{
        el.stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: 0
        });

        // Reset scrolled flag
        scrolled=0;
      }
  });
  
});
```

```css
div.nav-products-carousel {
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        background: rgb(201, 201, 116);
    }

    div.nav-item {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        white-space: initial;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .scroll-right {
        right: 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        background: #ccc;
        padding-top: 5%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100px;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
        background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
        background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="nav-products-carousel">
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">1</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">2</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">3</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">4</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">5</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">6</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">8</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item text-center">
            <a href="/mattresses/">
                <center><img class="img-fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" /></center>
                <p v-html="product.properties.Title">9</p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <span class="scroll-right text-white">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The above displayed have scrolling issue but [it works fine](https://fiddle.jshell.net/17r2v6hs/8/show/) on else.